# Error injecting angular $location service

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-services, angularjs-injector

I need to use `$location` service inside my `jQuery(callback)` function, so I tried to do the following:

```
$(function(){
    ... some stuff ...
    var $injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
    $injector.invoke(function($location){
        var url = $location.url();
    });
});
```

but all I get is `Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr]` logged in the console.
How can I use `$location` inside my jQuery callback?

Comment: What do you wish to do with `$location` inside the jQuery callback? It is usually not appropriate to even include jQuery in an Angular app, let alone intermix them. Surely there can be a better way to achieve this. But if you really want to mix the two worlds, you should at least decouple them with a custom *adapter* in-between.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that angular and jquery should not be mixed, I will try another solution! Thanks ;)